# Consuming rest api with Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I need to consume a rest API in my Drupal website and display the data as a table. Can you suggest me to how to do that ?
I am  new to Drupal so need to know where I need to add the custom code to fetch data and also I went through couple of modules but still did not get the clear picture on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 7 it was **drupal_http_request** however for Drupal 8, you can use Guzzle for that. You can find more detail with example here

https://www.drupal.org/node/1862446

Answer (score 0):

For consuming `REST` GET request

```php
<?php
/**
  * @file
  * Contains \Drupal\testmodule\Controller\TestController.
 */
namespace Drupal\testmodule\Controller;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;


public function current_contentp(){  

  $client = new Client();
  $json = $client->get('https://catfact.ninja/breeds')->getBody()->getContents(); 
 //..
}
```